# C++ return true if duplicates in a type int vector is found

Tags: c++, vector, boolean

Is there an easier way than writing a loop to check each and every value for duplicates, and return true when a duplicate within the vector is found?

Comment: Sure: `std::sort()` then `std::adjacent_find()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are theres a easier way than writing a loop checking each and every value for duplicates and return true when a duplicate within the vector is found?

You do have to check each and every element of the vector (until a duplicate is found), or else you cannot know whether one of the unchecked elements has duplicates or not.

If by "easier" you mean "more efficient" and if by "writing a loop" you mean two nested loops then yes, there is a more efficient way: Sort the vector first, then check only adjacent elements.

If by "easier" you mean "can I avoid writing any loops" then yes, you can. Both of the steps mentioned in previous paragraph (sort and check equivalence of adjacent elements) have an implementation in the standard library. The functions are named `sort` and `adjacent_find`.